# Select columns from a table vs Joining two tables

Tags: sql-server, performance, select, join, indexing

I want to take a decision between the performance of the following two scenarios.

1. Should I copy the same data of table-2 to table-1 creating same columns and fetch those data using simple SELECT query.

OR

2. Should I join two tables and fetch same data using JOIN.

**I have following things to play with:**

1. Table-1 --> More than 300,000 rows
2. Table-2 --> More than 200,000 rows
3. Composite PK with two columns which is necessary
4. Indexes on foreign keys
5. Many users (>50)
6. Much use of table in every reports and other functionalities

Comment: If you already have the data in two tables and can extract what you need using `JOINS`, it is counter-productive to denormalize and put the data in one table. Performance never depends on the number of rows of data. It depends on efficient table design, efficient indexes and efficient queries

Comment: Thanks raj for instant reply. According to the normalization rules it is counter productive but number of rows also matters and how many times it is queried will also matter for the performance of the server. Indexing and queries are proper as per the need. But When you join a table, every time it needs to query another table with join and instead if i can query only one table will it not affect the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create redundant data.

Use a join and have `COVERING INDEX` on the join field, or use `INCLUDE` the table2.field in the index you have for joint field (FK field).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX1
    ON Table2 (YourFK_Field)
    INCLUDE (TheRedundantField);
```

This way, when SQL Server reads the IX1, it will read the TheRedundantField as well.

You also can create covering index like this

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX1
    ON Table2 (YourFK_Field, TheRedundantField)
```

But it't not a good idea, as possibly TheRedundantField is a amount not a key field

Comment: Thanks FLICKER. Can you please show an example or something so that I can take a decision?

Comment: Thanks again FLICKER. Its useful. I will give it a try and get back to you soon.